# in bootstrap table the select dropdown menu displays default option after onchange performs

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have the following issue. Here is a cell in a bootstrap table created with flask jinja

```html
  <td>               
 <select id="{{idselectop}}" onchange="operazione_scelta_onchange({{ii}});" class="form-control" 
 name="operazione_scelta">
                       
                    {% for jj in ciclo_mysql %} 
                        {% if righe_estese[ii].operazione == jj[3] %}
                        <option value="{{jj[3]}}" selected>
                        {% else %}
                        <option value="{{jj[3]}}" >
                        {% endif %}
                            {{jj[3:6]|join('-')}}
                        </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </select> 
  </td>
```

When I choose one of the dropdown options, the onchange starts the following js function:

```js
function operazione_scelta_onchange(i) {
    
    let val = $("#operazione_scelta"+i).val(); 
    var ciclo_mysql_j = {{ciclo_mysql|tojson}};  
    for (let x = 0; x < ciclo_mysql_j.length; x++) {
        if (ciclo_mysql_j[x][3] === val) {

            $table.bootstrapTable('updateCell', {
                index: i,
                field: 'desc_op',
                value: ciclo_mysql_j[x][4]
                
            })
        }
    }
}
```

changing the value and the display of the value in another cell.

After that, in the cell containing the dropdown menu I see again the default option instead of the choosed one, i think because the table is reinitialised. If I set {reinit: false} in the updatecells parameters, the dropdown menu shows the choosed option but the cell to be updated shows the old value.
How can I solve?

Thankyou very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved using document.getElementById("stateSelect").selectedIndex = i;